# Can someone thoroughly explain this IsItPrime Function?

Tags: c++, primes

This is the function I found on CodeReview site, it determines if a number is a prime, while also handling negative numbers. There are few things I can't really catch up with.

1) Why is the first condition `<= 3` when it's supposed to deal with negatives?
2) What does `return n > 1` actually returns? And does it, in any way, affect other conditions?

```
bool IsItPrime(int n)
{
    if(n <= 3) {
        return n > 1;
    } else if(n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        for(int i(5); i * i <= n; i += 6) {
            if(n % i == 0 || n % (i + 2) == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think negative numbers can be prime. If you could consider negative numbers nothing would be prime since they would also have -1 and -n as factors.

Comment: The first part says all negative numbers return false, 1 returns false, and 2 and 3 return true

Comment: maybe the "handles also negatives" just means that it returns `false` for all negative inputs... can you give a link to the original post?

Comment: Note that this is a pretty poor algorithm. It tests `n % 35` even though that's pointless after `n%5` _or_  `n%7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(n <= 3) {
    return n > 1;
}
```

Is clever if not the easiest thing to reason out.  First you enter the if body if you have a number of 3 or less.  This covers the first 2 prime numbers plus all negative numbers, 0, and 1.  Then it goes on to `return n > 1;` this means that if `n` is greater than `1` you will return true, otherwise false.  So, if `n` is `2` or `3` the function will return `true`.  It is is less than `2` then it returns `false`. It would be the same as

```
 if (n <= 1) return false;
 else if (n == 2 || n == 3) return true
 else if ...
```

But as you can see that is more typing and adds an if statement.

Comment: I've never heard of such syntax before. Best answer I could've ever hoped for. Thanks man!

Comment: It would be interesting to add for which high `int`s the function results in UB... I think it's for every prime above the mathematical square(floor(sqrt(INT_MAX))).

Comment: @Rose There's nothing special in the syntax here. `n > 1` is an expression just like `n <= 3` in the if. You're just returning the result of that expression instead of using it in an if.

Comment: Just one more thing, I don't like taking things for granted. Could you introduce me to the logic of return n > 1 and it's result? As, why is it true if greater, and false if not.

Comment: @Kevin Oh, so that's pretty much the case of result vs effect?

Comment: @Rose `n > 1` is an expression.  When you do `if(n>1)` that `n>1` is evaluated and returns `true` if `n` is greater than `1` and `false` otherwise.  So `return n > 1;` returns the result of the expression `n > 1`.

Answer (score 1):

according to wikipedia:

> A prime number (or a prime) is a natural number greater than 1

`return n > 1` means return true for any number greater than 1, (i.e. 2 or 3, because this appears after the test `if n<=3`). 0, 1 or a negative number will make it return false.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Why is the first condition <= 3 when it's supposed to deal with
>   negatives?  2) What does return n > 1 actually returns?
>   These questions are linked:

The function can take a negative argument, but as you can see the first set of conditions tests if the argument is between 1 and 3. 2,3 being prime, it will return true, if the argument is 1,0 or negative, it will return false (so it doesn't really work with negative numbers).

Answer (score 0):

```
if(n <= 3) {
    return n > 1;
}
```

This will return false for all numbers less than or equal to 3, except for 2 and 3. This handles negative numbers as well (any negative number will be less than 3).

```
else if(n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0) {
    return false;
}
```

This does a modulus operation on your argument, and returns false if the number is divisible by 2 or 3 (which would also make it not prime). We're safe to call this even though 2 and 3 are divisible since they're are handled above.

```
else {
    for(int i(5); i * i <= n; i += 6) {
        if(n % i == 0 || n % (i + 2) == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This handles all other digits by looping until you're above the square root of a number. It also does modulus operations, this time with 5, 7, and all values n + 6, n + 8 (<11, 13>, <17, 19>, etc). We can iterate by 6 since we're doing the 2 and 3 modulus operations above.

Comment: *"This will return false for all numbers less than or equal to 3, except for 2."* means that 3 would produce `false,` but it produces `true`.